# Compare 2 files and print based on condition

Tags: python, perl, awk

I'm sorry if this kind of questions keeps getting asked, but I couldn't find while searching.

I have two files A and B. I need to create a file C which contains the differences in a format shown below:

File A:

```
foo1   2.1  3
foo2   3.1  3
foo3   4.1  3
foo4   2.1  3
foo5   3.1  3
```

File B:

```
foo1   2.0  2.9
foo2   2.1  3
foo4   2.1  3
```

File C (OUTPUT):  LHS contains values from File A. RHS contains values from File B (or just xxxx's if foo doesn't exist)

```
2.1  3  foo1   2.0  2.9
3.1  3  foo2   2.1  3
4.1  3  foo3   xxxxxxxx
2.1  3  foo4   2.1  3
3.1  3  foo5   xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: What have you tried, what are the problems you are having, and this smells like homework

Comment: Sorry, I just changed the format. I'm unable to go ahead with putting either types of values on the same line

Comment: Can you describe what the format of the output is supposed to be in words? It's not clear what you're looking for from your example.

Comment: If the file A's foo exists in file B, I'm appending the 2 values to it. Else if the file A's foo doesn't exist in file B, I'm just appending that row with xxxxx's. LHS contains values from File A. RHS contains values (or just xxxx's if foo doesn't exist) from File B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `awk`. Save first field of **fileB** as a key of a hash and the rest of fields as its value and compare for each line in **fileA** if the key exists, and print `xxxxxxxx` or the value of the hash.

Run next command:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        OFS = "\t";
    }

    FNR == NR {
        b[ $1 ] = $2 "\t" $3;
        next;
    }

    FNR < NR {
        str = ($1 in b) ? b[ $1 ] : "xxxxxxxx";
        print $2, $3, $1, str;
    }
' fileB fileA
```

With following output (tab separated fields):

```
2.1     3       foo1    2.0     2.9
3.1     3       foo2    2.1     3
4.1     3       foo3    xxxxxxxx
2.1     3       foo4    2.1     3
3.1     3       foo5    xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 35 seconds! +1

Comment: Done. Quick follow up - Is there a way to align column3 in the output file? Suppose we have foo1, foo2, foobar3, fooo4, etc. the formatting gets messed up.

Comment: @user1497417: In your shell, type: `tabs -10`  This will set a larger tab width and neaten your output. HTH.

Comment: @steve: Didn't know the `tabs` command. Good point. I use `column -t` for that, `awk '...' fileB fileA | column -t` to create an aligned table.

Answer (score 2):

Read through the two files and store the data in a hash keyed by the files' first fcolumn values.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = qw/ FileA.txt  FileB.txt /;
my %data;

for my $i (0, 1) {

  open my $fh, '<', $files[$i] or die qq(Unable to open "$files[$i]": $!);

  while (<$fh>) {
    s/\s+$//;
    my ($key, $val) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    $data{$key}[$i] = $val;
  }
}

for my $key (sort keys %data) {
  printf "%s  %s   %s\n",
      map $_ // 'xxxxxxxx', $data{$key}[0], $key, $data{$key}[1];
}
```

**output**

```
2.1  3  foo1   2.0  2.9
3.1  3  foo2   2.1  3
4.1  3  foo3   xxxxxxxx
2.1  3  foo4   2.1  3
3.1  3  foo5   xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$0; next; } { if ($1 in array) print $2, $3, array[$1]; else print $2, $3, $1, "xxxxxxxx"; }' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

Broken out on multiple lines:

```
FNR==NR {
    array[$1]=$0
    next
}

{
    if ($1 in array) {
        print $2, $3, array[$1]
    }
    else {
        print $2, $3, $1, "xxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Results:

```
2.1 3 foo1   2.0  2.9
3.1 3 foo2   2.1  3
4.1 3 foo3 xxxxxxxx
2.1 3 foo4   2.1  3
3.1 3 foo5 xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Quick follow up - Is there a way to align column3 in the output file? Suppose we have foo1, foo2, foobar3, fooo4, etc. the formatting gets messed up.

Comment: @user1497417: See Berei's answer and my comment above.